# I'd like to add omitted part of my dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

```
20/01/02 night     3
20/01/03 day      26
20/01/03 night     5
20/01/04 day       5
                  ..
23/01/16 night     2
23/01/17 day      10
23/01/17 night     5
23/01/18 day       6
23/01/18 night     1
```

index is YY/mm/dd day/night.
i'd like to add omitted the part of this dataframe.
during 20/01/02~23/01/18, it could have some omitted YY/mm/dd day or night.

and added count is 0.

do you have any idea?

thank you.

Comment: Your question is hard to understand. Do you want to print the whole dataframe?

Comment: that is the whole dataframe when print(df).

Comment: This isn't the whole dataframe but a shortened presentation of the dataframe. With `print(df.shape)` you can see the real number of rows and columns the dataframe has.

Comment: What give: `print(type(df))`, `print(type(df.index[0]),'>',df.index[0],'<', sep='')` and `print(type(df.index[1]),'>',df.index[1],'<', sep='')`. I need to be sure of the type of your *object* and of its index.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, here is a *proposition* with [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.pivot.html) and [`asfreq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.asfreq.html).

Assuming, you have a `df` with `df.columns = Index(['date', 'count'], dtype='object')`
:

```
out = (
        df.join(df["date"].str.extract("(.*) (day|night)"))
            .pivot(index=0, columns=1, values="count")
            .pipe(lambda df_: df_.set_index(pd.to_datetime(df_.index, yearfirst=True)))
            .asfreq("D").stack(dropna=False).reset_index(name="count")
            .assign(date= lambda x: x.pop(0).dt.strftime("%y/%m/%d").str.cat(x.pop(1), sep=" "))
            .fillna({"count": 0}, downcast="infer")
            [df.columns]
        )
```

Output :

```
print(out)

                date  count
0       20/01/02 day      0    # <- added
1     20/01/02 night      3
2       20/01/03 day     26
3     20/01/03 night      5
4       20/01/04 day      5
...              ...    ...
2221  23/01/16 night      2
2222    23/01/17 day     10
2223  23/01/17 night      5
2224    23/01/18 day      6
2225  23/01/18 night      1

[2226 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: no, it doesn't have any column

Comment: Wrong! A pandas _DataFrame_ do have columns (at least one). You just failed to describe yours. Can you add the output of `print(df.head(10).to_dict("list"))` to your question, please ?

Comment: TypeError: unsupported type: <class 'str'>

Comment: Unfortunately, if you ignore my comments/questions, my code won't work and will for sure throws an error. Your input is ambiguous, you need to share a reproducible example with `to_dict`. If you need some help from people, you need to make some little efforts ;)